# Rewrite rule not working, suspect redirect string

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

These rewrite rules are killing me. It is probable something little, but I can't find it.

I have a custom post type called **'tournament'**, it's permalink structure looks like

```
<domain>/<season>/<tournament-name>
```

For this custom post type everything works fine.

Now I have created a second custom post type **'match'**. I set hierarchy to false. I added a meta-box to match where I can select the tournament and store it as post_parent.

Now I want its permalink structure to look like:

```
<domain>/<season>/<tournament-name>/match/<match-name>
```

I use the `post_type_link` hook to add a filter that creates the permalink I want and the `init` hook to add the rewrite rule. The permalink is created as expected, but when using the rewrite rule, I keep getting 404's.

I flushed the rewrite rules both in code and manually.
I checked the regex and it's valid.
I suspect it is the redirect string, but I'm not sure.
Any suggestions or ideas?

```
function rat_match_post_type_link( $link, $post, $leavename, $sample ){

    if ( $post->post_type == 'match' ){

        $parent = get_post($post->post_parent);

        $season = get_post_meta( $parent->ID, 'rat-tournament-season', true);

        error_log (home_url( $season . '/' . $parent->post_name . '/match/' . $post->post_name));

        return home_url( $season . '/' . $parent->post_name . '/match/' . $post->post_name);
    } else {
        return $link;
    }
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'rat_match_post_type_link', 10, 4);

function rat_match_rewrite_rules()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('[0-9]{4}/(.+?)/match/([^/]+)?$','index.php?match=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action('init', 'rat_match_rewrite_rules');
```

*Note: I know I need to fix the post type link function in case there is no parent.*

**EDIT (8-feb-2019)**

While trying to investigate further I observed the following:

When I access:

```
http://local.wordpress.test/index.php?match=test-match
```

The result is:

```
http://local.wordpress.test/2019/the-hague-4-star/match/test-match?match=test-match
```

And the latter results in a 404.

Comment: have you tried setting `match` to just the match slug? Not sure why you’re inserting a different post type in there, especially since you say match is not hierarchical. If you need to pass tournament, you might have to put it in a custom query var so WP knows which post type you are actually trying to query.

Comment: Yes I did, that was an older attempt when I did have match as with a hierarchy to tournament. I updated the post to show your suggestion. The result (404) remains the same

Comment: Your rewrite rule works for me when I test it with an existing post type. Without knowing all of the details of the rest of your code, I can't say what the issue may be.

Comment: One quick question, did you specify a slug for your post type?